# Share variable between class methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm not a master in JavaScript. I'm starting use the OOP syntax and I have a small class like this one:

```
class Scraper {

    constructor() {}

    question(inputText) {
        rl.setPrompt(inputText);
        rl.prompt();
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            let answer;
            rl.on('line', (input) => {
                answer = input;
                rl.close();
            });
            rl.on('close', () => {
                resolve(answer);
            });
        })
    }

    startFetch(username) {
        this.username = String(username); 
        return axios({
                url: `https://www.instagram.com/${this.usernamee}/?__a=1`
            }).then( (response) => {
                //response.data.graphql.user);
                this.user_id = response.data.graphql.user.id;
                //totalMedia = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
                this.has_next_page = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page;
                response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map( (item, index) => {
                    this.processLink(item.node.display_url, index);
                });
                if( this.has_next_page ){
                    this.currCursor = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
                    this.fetchNextPage(this.user_id);
                } else {
                    console.log('Completed');
                }
                //let nodes = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.length;
            });
        
    }

    fetchNextPage(id) {
        return axios({
            method: 'GET',
            baseURL: 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/',
            params: {
              query_hash: '42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44',
              variables: { 
                id: id, 
                first: "12",  
                after: this.currCursor
              } 
            }
          }).then( (response) => {
            //console.log(response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node)
            //totalMedia = response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
            response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map( (item, index) => {
                index++;
                this.processLink(item.node.display_url, index);
            });
            if( response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page ){
                this.currCursor = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
            }
          });
    }

    processLink(imageURI, n) {
        let filename = path.format({dir: destinationPath, base: `${n}.jpg`});
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
        https.get(imageURI, (res) => {
            res.pipe(file);
        });
    }
}
```

How I can set a variable inside a method and then share it and overwrite if needed inside another method of the same class? The class I'm creating is responsible to scrape an Instagram public profile. After the first request, as suggested to me here I'm calling the `fetchNextPage` method. To make it works as expected I need to set the `currCursor` variable and maintain it updated with the new cursors after each request. will the `this.user_id` be set and called from the method, and the `this.currCursor` will be updated with new value?

Comment: well a class in javascript is simply an object. an object can have properties. the property can be used in the entire class aka Object and accessed via "this" keyword. Example: this.currCursor = someValue. does that answer your question?

Comment: You're asking if something will work in a certain way if the code is run. The simplest way of finding that out is to run the code and see if that something works in that certain way.

Comment: Why are you currently using a class that doesn't have any state?

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean with state?I'm not a JS programmer and I'm new to oop in Javascript.

Comment: @famoha ok, so as I was expecting, the value of `this.user_id` or `this.currCursor` can be declared inside a method and modified or accessed from other class methods. Thank you for the simple and quick clarification

Comment: @newbiedev you're welcome :)